# Create an RSS feed for Joomla! 2.5.7

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, rss

I'm new to Joomla and I can't find how to create an RSS feed for my own content.  Everywhere I look trys to set up a feed to import content from other's sites.  All I'm looking for is the equivalent of what Wordpress has at http://www.example.com/feed

Is there a URL like this for all new content that is created for Joomla?  I saw a tutorial that gave me the impression you have to set up a feed for each category manually, but that was for Version 1.7 and the options they discussed aren't there now.

Any help or direction on this matter would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You can check any of the 3rd party extensions, ex: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/social-display/rss-readers/21112 or just search the repository for something that would match your needs: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/social-edition/automatic-articles

Comment: All the plugins I saw are to show feeds.  I want to create a feed of my own content.

Comment: what is your content, is it core Joomla articles?

Comment: Yes.  I would like to create a feed of articles that I've created in one or two different categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the core components wll automatically create feeds for you. You can see how to do it in any view.feed.php file if you need to do it in your own extension.

The integration option for each component let you set some parameters for that.

Also you can enable the syndication module if you want to show users the link for the feed on pages with feeds which is basically all category and featured layouts.

Comment: So if I wanted to get the URL of a feed for Category XXX, what would that be?  Where would I find it?  I'm sorry, I'm very new to Joomla.  I do 99% of my work with Wordpress.

Comment: index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=2&Itemid=106&format=feed&type=rss

Comment: What if you wanted the RSS feed to work with multiple Joomla categories?

Comment: It's not really designed for that though you could probably work it out by playing with the featured view, but I think I would use tags instead and maybe make a plugin to automatically tag articles in certain categories with a specific tag and then producing a feed for that tag.  Or maybe automatically map each category to a tag ... that would really help a lot of things.

Answer (score 2):

yoursite.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=2&format=feed&type=rss

replace 2 with the id of the category of your posts